# Issue due to iframe

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

I am having two radio buttons(traverse and direct) in a jsp form.Traverse for submitting form normally and Direct for sumbitting the form using iframe.After submitting the form using iframe ,if i try to submit normally,the application is opening in new window.How to prevent the form from opening in new window.

```
function submitAction() {       
        var fileValue = document.getElementById("file1").value;     
        if (fileValue == "") {
            alert("Please uploaded file type of .war or .html type");
            return false;

        }           
        var valuePassed = getCheckedRadio();
        var url="uploadfile.do?rad=" + valuePassed;     
        if (valuePassed == "traverse") {                    
            document.EntryForm.action = url; 
            document.EntryForm.submit();    //Normal way of submitting.                         
        }else if (valuePassed == "direct") {
            alert("direct");    
            url=url+"&fileName="+fileValue;             
            directConvert(document.EntryForm,url,'downloaddiv');                }
    }



function directConvert(form, action_url, div_id){               
        // Create the iframe...
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");     
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");
        // Add to document...
        form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
        //window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";     
        iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");     
        // Add event...

        var eventHandler = function () {     
                if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);             
                // Message from server...    

                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {                
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {                    
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {                 
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }               
                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;     
                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)',50);
            }

        if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
        if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);  

        // Set properties of form...
        form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
        form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");  
        form.submit();              
    }
```

when i try traverse first time it is working properly but after submitting through iframe,if i try traverse it is opening in new window.How to prevent it from opening in New window.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the `form` object of `EntryForm` to the iframe and changing the `form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");` while doing a `directConvert` submit.

So the `form` target remains so even when you try to submit through `traverse` but since the `iframe` is removed (`setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)',50);`) from the page it opens in a new window after submit instead of the `iframe`.

So you can change back the `target` to `_self` in `traverse` submit: `document.EntryForm.target = "_self"`.

By the way `target` attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) in HTML 4.01.

Comment: document.EntryForm.target = "_self"; document.EntryForm.action = url; document.EntryForm.submit(); whether it will work ?

Comment: I think it should work. Let me know if it doesn't. You can also try a variation: `formTraverse = document.EntryForm;
formTraverse.setAttribute("action", url);
formTraverse.setAttribute("target", "_self");
formTraverse.submit();`